# Writing to existing xml file using StAX

Tags: java, xml, file, io, stax

I'm using StAX to add new Record object to an XML file named "archive.xml". General method is:

1. Check if file exists, if not - create new one;
2. Create XMLEventReader and XMLEventWriter;

   3.1 If file was created according to first item of the list, just add record to "archive.xml" using writer;

   3.2. If file existed, read all content from "archive.xml" and parallely write it to "temp.xml", then in the end add new Record. Rewrite "archive.xml" with "temp.xml".

But the last stage of item 3.2 throws an error `java.nio.file.FileSystemException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process (in sun.nio.fs.WindowsException)`.
What may be the problem?

```
    public boolean create(Record record) {
        String fileName="archive.xml"
        boolean flag = false;
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
                flag = true;
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.err.println("Can't create new file");
                return false;
            }
        }
        //Create StAX reader and writer
        XMLEventReader reader=null;
        XMLEventWriter writer=null;
        try {
            XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
            XMLOutputFactory xmlOutputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
            XMLEventFactory eventFactory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();

            if (flag) {//if writing to new file
                writer = xmlOutputFactory.createXMLEventWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));
                /*using writer here*/
            writer.close();
            } else {//if adding to existing file
                File temp=new File("temp.xml");
                writer = xmlOutputFactory.createXMLEventWriter(new FileOutputStream(temp));
                reader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream(file));
                while (reader.hasNext()) {
               /*reading from "archive.xml", writing to "temp.xml"
               in the end - adding new Record to "temp.xml"*/
                }
                    reader.close();
                    writer.close();
//trying to rewrite "archive.xml" with "temp.xml" (but cannot get access to file)
                   try {
 Files.move(Path.of(temp.toURI()),Path.of(file.toURI()),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
            System.err.println("File not found");
        } catch (XMLStreamException xmlStreamException) {
           xmlStreamException.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                if(reader!=null)
                reader.close();
                if(writer!=null)
                writer.close();
            } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: you should follow the stack trace to be sure. line numbers will be your clue.. seems like you may. be creating file twice.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes to my code - now it works fine:

1. The new file (if not exists) is now created by `FileOutputStream` (no call to `file.createFile()` anymore). Probably the `FileOutputStream` created a file again after `file.createFile()`.
2. `FileOutputStream` and `FileInputStream` are now conrete objects and I close them explicitly. Probably the `XMLEventWriter` didn't close the `FileOutputStream` it was using, when I called `writer.close()`. Is it normal?

Here is the code:

```
public boolean create(Record record) {
    String fileName="archive.xml"

    File file = new File(fileName);
    boolean flag;
    flag=  !file.exists();

    //Create StAX reader and writer
    XMLEventReader reader=null;
    XMLEventWriter writer=null;
    //Create output and input streams
    FileOutputStream os;
    FileInputStream is;

    try {
        XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLOutputFactory xmlOutputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLEventFactory eventFactory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();

        if (flag) {//if writing to new file
           os=new FileOutputStream(file);
            writer = xmlOutputFactory.createXMLEventWriter(os);
            /*using writer here*/
        os.close();
        writer.close();
        } else {//if adding to existing file
            File temp = new File("temp.xml");
            os=new FileOutputStream(temp);
            writer = xmlOutputFactory.createXMLEventWriter(os);
            is=new FileInputStream(file) ;
            reader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(is);
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
           /*reading from "archive.xml", writing to "temp.xml"
           in the end - adding new Record to "temp.xml"*/
            }
                is.close();
                reader.close();
                os.close();
                writer.close();
               //trying to rewrite "archive.xml" with "temp.xml"
               try {      Files.move(Path.of(temp.toURI()),Path.of(file.toURI()),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
        System.err.println("File not found");
    } catch (XMLStreamException xmlStreamException) {
       xmlStreamException.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            if(is!=null)
                is.close();
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
            if(os!=null)
                os.close();
            if (writer != null)
                writer.close();
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```